# decltype and typeid returns different type

Tags: polymorphism, c++14

the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public :
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "from base class\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public :
    void print() override { std::cout << "from derived class \n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr< Base > d = std::make_unique< Derived >();
    std::cout << typeid( *( d.get() ) ).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid( decltype( *( d.get() ) ) ).name() << "\n";
}
```

the first one outputs
7Derived
but the second one outputs 4Base.
shouldn't both of them outputs the same type ? ( 7Derived )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is as expected, and the difference is if the static type of a pointer or the type of the pointed-to object is used.

The first case, using `d` directly: as `d` points to an object of type `Derived`. Here, it is the actual (run-time) type of the object that is printed.

In the `decltype` case:, it is the *static type of the expression* that is used. As `d` is a `unique_ptr<Base>`, the type of `d.get()` is `Base*`, and dereferencing that gives a `Base`.

Comment: Is there a way to make decltype return the runtime type of the object ? If it is not possible, I have got other design, but I would prefer this kind of design

Comment: No, decltype is a compile time construct and the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: ok then...I guess I will just resort to dynamic_cast. This has been helpful